# Getting UITextField value and sending it with in a in-app email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have one UITextField that has a value and one UILabel that has text. I have added an in-app email button that works. I would like to add the UITextField's value and the UILabel's text to the body of the email. 
Example code:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tkw1976@gmail.com" , nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"Subject"];
    [composer setMessageBody:@"This is the body" isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
```

I would like the messageBody to look like this:

> sandwiches(UILabel) 10(UITextField)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're practically there. Make connections for your `UILabel` and `UITextField`, and then set the text of the message by

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sandwiches %@ 10 %@",label.text,textField.text];
[composer setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: I was using "sandwiches 10" as an example for the message body.

Comment: I'm still having problems with getting getting the textField information to show up in the in app email.